# Find a function in MATLAB that can help to find random numbers

Tags: matlab

Can anyone help me please in these situation:
I would like to generate a series of random numbers that obeys a given distribution in **MATLAB** 
by using Monte Carlo Simulation

For example: exponential distribution  `p(x)=exp(-x)  x>0`

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general-purpose solution to this problem.  You will need to combine e.g. `rand()` with a technique such as [*inverse transform sampling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Comment: E.g. `X = -log1p(-rand(1,10000));hist(X,25);` will show an exponential distribution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `random` command from the Statistics Toolbox.  For example, to create 100 random numbers from an exponential distribution with mean 5, you would write:

```
random('Exponential', 5, 100, 1)
```

For more details, see the documentation for the [random](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/random.html) command.